# Making a Slack Bot to answer 'Yes' or 'No' depending on a certain condition

Tags: slack, slack-api

I want to make a Bot that replies 'Yes' or 'No' to a question, but will answer differently depending on a certain condition.

I help run a summer camp, and we use Slack as our inter-office messaging system among the staff. We frequently have storms pop-up, and if we have thunder or lightning in the area we have to cancel outside activities for at least 30 minutes. I have set up a program to announce bad weather, but sometimes the weather problems last longer then 30 minutes. So I an constantly asked if we are still under a weather watch. If there a way I can set up a bot that people can ask if we are under a weather watch and it will respond 'Yes' or 'No'

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. We are ready to help you, but this forum is for specific questions only and your question is a bit too broad. I would advise to checkout a tutorial. But please feel free to come back once you have a more specific question. https://api.slack.com/tutorials

Comment: But if you are looking for a forum to have a more broader discussion and get help. Checkout Slack on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Slack/